# Scroll-based Video start on enter viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, html5-video

I set up a page with 4 blocks, a video is controlled by scrolling up/down on block 3.
The video is sticky to block 3.
Problem: the video should only start when entering the veiwport, not on scroll position block 1.

My Java Script knowledge is very poor, so I ask here for help to write/implement such a function.
Here is what I have tinkered so far:

HTML

```
 <div class="divit" style="height:200vh; background-color: bisque;">
        <h1>Block 01</H1>
    </div>

    <div class="divit" style="height:200vh; background-color: rgb(95, 120, 145);">
        <h1>Block 02</H1>
    </div>

    <div class="divit" style="height:1600vh; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
        <h1 class="overlay1">Block 03</H1>
        <video id="v0" tabindex="0", autobuffer preload>
            <source type='video/mp4; codecs=&quot;avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2&quot;' src="scroll_sync_video_a.mp4"></source>
        </video>
    </div>

    <div class="divit" style="height:100vh; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
        <h1>Block 04</H1>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
        body {
            padding:0px;
            margin:0px;
            font-family: 'Arial';
        }

        #v0 {
            display: inline-block;
            position: sticky;
            position: -webkit-sticky;
            top:0px;
            width: 70%;
        }

        .divit {
            text-align: center;
            display: block;
            z-index: 1;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
        }

        h1 {
            margin: 0px auto;
            padding: 10%;
            font-size: 16em;
            background: #80dbff80;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .overlay1 {
            z-index: 10;
            position: absolute;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 10%;
            font-size: 16em;
            color:azure;
            background: #ffffff0c;
            display: inline-block;
        }
```

JS

```
        // start video at frame 0
        var frameNumber = 0,
        
        // lower numbers = faster playback
        playbackConst = 1000, 

        // select video element         
        vid = document.getElementById('v0'); 
        


    // Use requestAnimationFrame for smooth playback
    function scrollPlay(){  
    var frameNumber  = window.pageYOffset/playbackConst;
    vid.currentTime  = frameNumber;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollPlay);
    }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollPlay);
```

Here is the HTML test-page:
http://scroll.bfg.lu/

Code reference: https://github.com/designcourse/html5-video-scroll/blob/master/index.html

Comment: Would IntersectionObserver be useful here?

Comment: @AHaworth Hello, thank you! This is very interesting. But I think the handling of this function requires a lot of Java Script knowledge which I don't have. :-( I'm lost in this.

Comment: MDN has examples. It’s worth learning about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the topOffset of the block 3 and calculate the frame as:

```
const block3 = document.querySelector("#block3");
const frameNumber  = Math.max(0,window.pageYOffset - block3.offsetTop)/playbackConst;
```

For this to work you need to add the id "block3" to your block3 div

Comment: Thank you for the offset idea! I'll add this to the code:-) I updated the URL http://scroll.bfg.lu/ But it stops at frame 0. I missed somthing?

Comment: You need to update the frameNumber on every scroll event for this to work.

Comment: Sorry, I checked your code and saw that you are not calculating the frameNumber inside the scrollPlay function. Move the formula inside the function (you can get rid of the frameNumber declaration outside scrollPlay, it is not used outside).

Comment: OK, it works fine like this, thank you:     function scrollPlay(){  
    const block3 = document.querySelector("#block3");
    const frameNumber  = Math.max(0,window.pageYOffset - block3.offsetTop)/playbackConst;vid.currentTime  = frameNumber;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollPlay);
    }

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer to summerize.

The code should be written like this:

```
    <script>

    // start video at frame 0
    var frameNumber = 0,
    
    // lower numbers = faster playback
    playbackConst = 1000, 

    // select video element         
    vid = document.getElementById('v0'); 
    
// Use requestAnimationFrame ID
function scrollPlay(){  
const block3 = document.querySelector("#block3");
const frameNumber  = Math.max(0,window.pageYOffset - block3.offsetTop)/playbackConst;vid.currentTime  = frameNumber;
window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollPlay);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollPlay);

</script>
```

Big thanks to a Frend and @Jose.